# How to remove all content of QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I'm using Qt 5.12. I want to remove all items from combo Box at a time. is there any procedure to remove all items at a time without removing one by one index.

Comment: Why [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#clear) not helping?

Comment: @eyllanesc i have the same problem but with QML ComboBox. In QML ComboBox there is no clear option. Also settings combobox model to: model: [ ] did not help. Any idea how to remove all items of QML combobox from qml?

Comment: @peco create a question where you provide a [MRE]

Answer (score 9):

If you take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html you will see the function `clear()`.

Function description:

> “Clears the combobox, removing all items.
> Note: If you have set an external model on the combobox this model will still be cleared when calling this function.”